# How to do feature selection after using pre-trained word embeddings?

Tags: nlp, feature-selection, feature-engineering

I am working on a multiclass text classification problem. I want to use the top k features based on mutual information (`mutual_info_classif`) for training my model.

I started this project on ML models:

I used `tfidf` for feature extraction and then used `mutual_info_classif` for feature selection.

```py
    svc = Pipeline([('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),
                   ('ig', SelectKBest(mutual_info_classif,k=1000)),
                   ('clf',LinearSVC(multi_class='ovr')),
              ])
    svc.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = svc.predict(X_test)
```

This was pretty straight-forward.

Next, I started to work on RNN (more specifically a simple LSTM model)and that is where I am having a problem.

I have used pre-trained word embeddings from GloVe (300d) to get features from my data.
The embedding matrix I feed into the embedding layer of my RNN has the shape (4293,300), 4293 is the number of unique words found in my data and 300 is the dimension.

**My questions are:** Is there any way that I can use the top 1000 words (features) out of these 4293 based on `mutual_info_classif`? Is it even possible to do so? If yes, then should it be done before making the embedding_matrix or after?

Answer (score 1):

When using a RNN, you don't feed all the data at once, you usually have a seq2seq model.
The models are created with an encoder-decoder architecture. The LSTM is used in the encoding phase.

So, let's say you have a text of `78` words. You will feed the embedding vector (size `300`) of those `78` words, 1-by-1 into your LSTM and in the end you will get a `hidden vector` which represents your sentence.

Then, you can take this `hidden vector` and use it for classification (with a feedforward neural network, for example).

So, it doesn't matter that you have `4293` unique words in your data. You need to feed your LSTM a sequence of size `[<number of words in sentence> × 300]`.

Comment: Agreed. But, what if for that particular sentence, I want that out of those 78 words, only the top 30 words (based on mutual info) to be fed into the LSTM? Is that even possible?

Suppose, I somehow reduce my embedding matrix from (4293,300) to (1000,300) by picking the top 1000 words using mutual_info. Now, when that 78-word sentence will be fed to the LSTM, will not only those words (30 out of 78) be fed which are present in the embedding matrix currently?  If yes, then I come back to my original question: How to get the embedding matrix from (4293,300) to (1000,300) using mutual_info?

Comment: Ok. If you have, 1)  a lot of smaller sentences, then I would you suggest you score each word in a sentence based on their TF-IDF Score, and if you have 2) fewer but large sentences (e.g. size >4000) then I would suggest you use a summarization algorithm, **However**, with either approach, keep the original words sequence, because an LSTM expects that sequence to be there.

Answer (score 0):

**You lose the point of word matrix if you do that.**

Whole point is, very roughly speaking, when you pre-deterimened your word dictionary to calculate **distributed representation** of words. In other words information of one word will be in other words-vectors also.